# desktop empty: no icons & folders, no mouse actions

Tags: gnome, desktop-icons

My desktop fails for one of the users (2) only:

- No icons
- No action upon right mouse button

(For user 2 all is fine. Users can be switched during session, then no issues for user 2. Back again to user 1: same problem again)

Only way to operate under user 1 is by general menu.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mint is off-topic here. Try https://forums.linuxmint.com.

Comment: A similar issue was raised on multiple occasions in the ubuntu forums. None of the solutions offered there solve my case. That does not imply, though, that this issue is mint-specific. You cannot tell whether it is off topic, because it might be a more general ubuntu issue. (Mint is based on ubuntu).

Comment: Whatever, ... thanks for suggestion to look into Unix & Linux. The answer was found there. But note that the answer  IS not regarding mint, but rather (in my opinion) an Ubuntu thing (correct me if I am wrong). Here the answer was found: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406067/no-active-desktop-in-linux-mint. Or should I conclude that it is a gnome issue? Consider the matter SOLVED. best regards, Roland

Comment: **I've removed the answer from the question and voted to re-open.**  Once 4 additional reviewers agree with me, please feel free to post your answer in the answer box that will open below.  You will still be able to copy-paste your answer from the [revision history](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1152245/revisions)  **0:-) ;-)**

Comment: @Roland Go ahead and post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer (found on [No active Desktop in Linux Mint - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406067/no-active-desktop-in-linux-mint/525816#525816)):

Launch `dconf-editor` & navigate to <kbd>org</kbd> → <kbd>gnome</kbd> →  <kbd>desktop</kbd> →  <kbd>background</kbd> & check the box labeled `show-desktop-icons`.

The cause of the error is unclear to me. Similar issues were reported over the past 6(!) years for various Linux environments including Ubuntu Unity. Key words:

- Desktop doesn't show anything
- After installing Gnome, desktop folder doesn't appear on my desktop
- Desktop disappeared
- Desktop icons missing
- Etc.

It could be a Gnome issue, or a Mint issue (buggy interconnection of desktop settings to Gnome?). For further consideration by developers.

[image: GUI of dconf-editor]

Comment: An edit *and and upvote!*  **;-)**  Also: please [edit] and correct the link.